# How to get a Single line of an EditText, add it to a Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have this 2 lines in the EditText:

```
%Print "HI"%      
%Print "I love StackOverFlow"%
```

How to add only this   `"  --)2TEXT's(--  "`   to a listview?

Comment: Do you mean adding the text in the quotes of edittext, to each line in a listview? If yes try String.split("\\"")

Comment: Yes, want to add the text in the " " but i want to check if its %Print and remove this: [ %Print "  " % ]

Comment: Use String str = sourceStr.split("\\"")[1] and you will get the text within the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using String.split(). Code example:

```
String multiLines = editText.getText().toString();
String[] streets;
String delimiter = "\n";

streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);
```

Now you have an array of streets.
Then create an ArrayAdapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_items, R.id.textView, streets);
```

Then attach the arrayAdapter to your ListView like this:

```
ListView simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I would recommend switching to RecyclerView

Comment: Do u know how to, if its %Print remove the "" ?

Comment: string.replace("\\"", "")